# Refresh InfoPath field after code-based calculation

Tags: infopath2010

I have an InfoPath 2010  form that creates a new Sharepoint list item. The form has, in essence, one input field and one output field. If something gets entered in the input field then some calculation is performed and I want the result to show up in the output field.As the calculation is somewhat complicated I need to do it in code, not through rules.

```
private void CalculateOutput()
{
    XPathNavigator main = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
    XPathNavigator service = main.SelectSingleNode("my:meineFelder/my:serviceValue", NamespaceManager);
    double serviceValue = service.ValueAsDouble;
    double output = 3*serviceValue;   // much abbreviated version

    // output now has the correct value
    XPathNavigator outputNav = main.SelectSingleNode("my:meineFelder/my:output", NamespaceManager);

    //Remove the "nil" attribute (otherwise we get an error when the field is a double instead of a string)
    if (outputNav.MoveToAttribute("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))  outputNav.DeleteSelf();

    outputNav.SetValue(output.ToString());
 }
```

My problem is that everything works fine in the InfoPath preview but once I deploy the form and run it in the browser the output field does not get updated, i.e. I cannot see the result of my calculations.

I have tried .ReplaceSelf (with OuterXML), with zero result. I have also played with assigning the result to another field and thereby firing an "set field value" rule, also to no avail.

If I submit the form, the output value is saved OK but I'd really like the user to see the output field before submitting.

Any Ideas?
Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case of browser enabled form, ensure that you have set the "Postback Setting" to refresh "Always"

To do this right Click on the control on which the postback is to be triggered. (in your case Service value). Go to *Browser Forms* tab and set the *Postback Setting* to `Always`.